# How to rectify the error of isfinitenot supported for input types?

Tags: python, numpy

I am joining two csv files based on an ID and then populating the values from right csv to left csv. Please find the below code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
df=pd.read_csv("I:/SIT/Monthly/Target/drugmonthly3.csv")
df1=pd.read_csv("I:/SIT/Monthly/prosinbound340b.csv")
df2=merge(left=df,right=df1,left_on="NDC_ID",right_on="NDC",how='left')
df2=df2[np.isfinite(df2['NDC'])]
a=df2["340b Cost"]
print(a)
df["PER_UNIT_340B"]=a
df=df[np.isfinite(df['PER_UNIT_340B'])]
df4=pd.DataFrame(df)
df3=pd.DataFrame.to_csv(df4,"I:/SIT/Monthly/340b.csv",index=False).
```

I am getting an error as ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: What is the type of the input to the `isfinite` function?

Comment: I'd advise omitting the `import as *` lines, and use `np....` and `pd....` for all functions.

Comment: Well, I think a good start would be describing what the CSV files contain. It sounds like `isfinite` is being applied to a non-number.